# Create Bitmap from URI creates huge lag

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am trying to make a gallery app which shows pictures you share to it, but I need to be able to display portrait images in portrait mode, and simply using .setImageUri puts the in vertical mode. So I create a Bitmap out of it and then rotate it. The problem is, that it needs too much time to create this bitmap. Here is the code:

```
            Log.d("r", "rotating: start");
            btmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), urinormal);
            Log.d("r", "rotating: unrotated bitmap created");

10-26 23:12:43.782 32171-32171/com.gtp.showapicturetoyourfriend D/r: rotating: start
10-26 23:12:44.130 32171-32171/com.gtp.showapicturetoyourfriend D/r: rotating: unrotated bitmap created
```

As you see, it takes about half a second to create a bitmap, which is much too long. Is there a better way to do all of this?

Comment: Rotate the `ImageView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare already tried that, but the imageview is fullscreen and the dimensions get kind of messed up if I do this.

Comment: What is the resolution of that bitmap?

Comment: `urinormal`. Where did you get that uri from?

Comment: @greenapps The imageView is as big as the screen (matchparent) and the resolution depends on the picture. The uri is being sent as an intent from any other activity by sharing.

Comment: Well if you do not want to give to the point info... There is nothing in your code that adapts resolution... So all pretty vague. I still dont know what kind of uri.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry for not being more specific. The app receives an implicit intent, from which I extract an URI in the form of content://data/thing/something/2342365356